# On input JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input, jquery-selectors

I am trying to make a realtime input validation to the following day inout element:

```js
$('#new_day').on('input', function() {
  $(".days > option").each(function() {
    if ($('#new_day').val() == $("option")) {
      $('#new_day_save').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#new_day_save').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="days">
   <option>Monday</option>
   <option>Friday</option>
</select>
<p>You have another proposition? Add it to the list.</p>
<input id="new_day" type="text" />
<input id="new_day_save" type="button" value="save new day" />
```

I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: There is no element with `id="day"` !!

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the current option text `$(this).text()` in the condition like :

```
$(".days > option").each(function() {
    if( input_value == $(this).text()){
        $('#new_day_save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** Remove the disabled outside of the each method.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#new_day').on('input', function(){
   //Get input value
   var input_value = $(this).val(); 
   
   //Remove disabled from the button
   $('#new_day_save').removeAttr('disabled'); 
   
   //iterate through the options 
   $(".days > option").each(function() {
      //If the input value match option text the disable button
      if( input_value == $(this).text()){
          $('#new_day_save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="days">
   <option>Monday</option>
   <option>Friday</option>
</select>
<p>You have another proposition? Add it to the list.</p>
<input id="new_day" type="text" />
<input id="new_day_save" type="button" value="save new day"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get array of `option` texts and check if that array includes input value.

```js
$('#new_day').on('input', function() {
  var opts = $('select option').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  }).get();

  $('#new_day_save').prop('disabled', opts.includes($(this).val()))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="days">
  <option>Monday</option>
  <option>Friday</option>
</select>
<p>You have another proposition? Add it to the list.</p>
<input id="new_day" type="text" />
<input id="new_day_save" type="button" value="save new day" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you are comparing `$('#new_day').val()` with `$("option")` which will never match because you can not get text/value using `$("option")`.

You can use  `$(this).text()` OR `$(this).val()` in place of `$("option")` and it will work.

Your correct code will be as below

```js
$('#new_day').on('input', function(){
   $(".days > option").each(function() {
      if($('#new_day').val() == $(this).text()){
        $('#new_day_save').prop('disabled', true);
      }else{
        $('#new_day_save').prop('disabled', false);
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script should look something like this:

```js
// start with a disabled button
$('#new_day_save').prop('disabled', true);

$('#new_day').on('input', function(){
     var dayExists = false;
     // use console log or echo to debug your script
     // console.log($('#new_day').val());
     $(".days > option").each(function() {
        if($('#new_day').val() == $(this).val()){
            dayExists = true;
        }
     });
     //console.log(dayExists);
     $('#new_day_save').prop('disabled', !dayExists);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="days">
   <option>Monday</option>
   <option>Friday</option>
</select>
<p>You have another proposition? Add it to the list.</p>
<input id="new_day" type="text" />
<input id="new_day_save" type="button" value="save new day"/>
```